# how to hide property page from some resource type

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

my application project contains a different type of resources. for some IFolder not all folders in the project I need to set property page on right click properties.
my problem is that this page is shown for all folders even the property tester returns false.

plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
  <page
        class="com.my.ui.properties.PropertiesPage"
        id="com.my.ui.properties.Properties"
        name="page">
     <enabledWhen>
        <adapt
              type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
           <test
                 property="com.my.ui.propertyTester.supperFolder">
           </test>
        </adapt></enabledWhen>
 </page>

 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
        class="com.my.ui.properties.FolderTester"
        id="com.my.ui.propertyTester"
        namespace="com.my.ui.propertyTester"
        properties="supperFolder"
        type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
  </propertyTester>
```

```java
public class FolderTester extends PropertyTester {

@Override
public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args, Object expectedValue) {
    if ("supperFolder".equals(property) && receiver instanceof IFolder) {
        IFolder folder = (IFolder) receiver;
        if (IWResourceManager.getInstance().isIWResource(folder)) {
            ..
            ..
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. I can only suggest checking the property tester return values again.

Answer (score 0):

after hours of debugging, i finally found the mistake, I fill like I need to share it, in case someone has the same problem... 
so.. 
in property tester extension point, tester "id" and "namespace" had the same value and that's was creating some sort of conflict.